# Set of a interface in typeScript

Tags: typescript, set

I was trying to create a Set of interface like following : -

```
export enum Region {
    US_EAST_1 = "us-east-1",
    EU_WEST_1 = "eu-west-1"
}

export interface RegionBasedTable {
    readonly region: string;
    readonly tableName: string;
}

export const set: Set<RegionBasedTable> = new Set([
        [Region.EU_WEST_1, "firstTable"],
    [Region.EU_WEST_1, "SecondTable"],
    [Region.EU_WEST_1, "ThirdTable"],
    [Region.EU_WEST_1, "FourthTable"],
    [Region.EU_WEST_1, "FifthTable"]]
    );
```

But this is throwing errors . I think the way , i have put the values in Set is not correct .
Can someone please correct me in this , how can i create the set of interface ?

Thanks .

Comment: Did you meant to use `Map<Region, RegionBasedTable>`? Also to prevent repetition, you can do `new Set<RegionBasedTable>(...)` to not repeat

Comment: No , i want to use set only as EU_WEST_1 can have multiple tableName . I just want to store them  in a set .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close to what you were trying to accomplish. It might help you.

This solution combines `Map` with `Set`, it is a very fast data structure.

```js
export enum Region {
    US_EAST_1 = "us-east-1",
    EU_WEST_1 = "eu-west-1",
    US_WEST_1 = "us-west-1"
}

export interface RegionBasedTable {
    readonly region: Region;
    readonly tableName: string;
}

export const map = new Map<Region, Set<RegionBasedTable["tableName"]>>([
    [Region.EU_EAST_1, new Set("firstTable", "SecondTable", "ThirdTable", "FourthTable")],
    [Region.EU_WEST_1, new Set("FifthTable")],
);

map.get(Region.EU_EAST_1)?.has('firstTable') // true;
map.get(Region.EU_WEST_1)?.has('firstTable') // false;
map.get(Region.US_WEST_1)?.has('firstTable') // undefined;
```

Answer (score 2):

You've type the set to contain `RegionBasedTable` types, which are objects that each have two properties: `region` and `tableName`.

However, the values you are putting in the set are arrays.

The set is expecting:

```
{ region: Region.EU_WEST_1, tableName: "firstTable" }
```

But you are providing:

```
[Region.EU_WEST_1, "firstTable"]
```

So if you change the format of your set items, it should work as you expect:

```
export const set: Set<RegionBasedTable> = new Set([
  { region: Region.EU_WEST_1, tableName: "firstTable" },
  { region: Region.EU_WEST_1, tableName: "SecondTable" },
  // etc.
]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=15&ssc=4&pln=11&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwErAOYEsKJwDeAUHOXAKoDKA+gKICC1AKrQIxwC8cARMgGcAtMACGAmEPa8ANGQr1KtAOr1WHbn2DIhAd2ASpvEgF8SJUJFhxciGMCgAzUQGNgmHPkQAhccAAmLKIARgA27qQUcFBi-gShAJ7RngQAXHASULbYANzy5DGicYiJcDAh4QByoqjA6ZnZeWYW4NDwLgQSGcAw6dQ9ADxYeAS+AgFBYcAAfJqIwLpw-TAAFADa8kTJI4jpw14AdIoqamzsMmUVwNW16byOuFASk+G8cCZy5FsxO3spiEclKp1OdLlMbnU+P0OohAlc3h95AB6JEIGAuA4kAC6AEockA)

---

However, checking for these values *in the set* is another matter.

In javascript, arrays and objects have identity equivalence. That means they are equal if they are the same object. Two different objects that have the same content are not considered equal. This is the equality check that a set will use to determine if it contains something.

```
const a = { prop: 'value' }
const b = { prop: 'value' }
console.log(a === b) // false
```

In this example `a` is a different object than `b` and so they are not equal.

Now lets try with a set:

```
const a = { prop: 'value' }
const set = Set(a)
console.log(set.has({ prop: value })) // false
console.log(set.has(a)) // true
```

In this case you made an object `a` and put it in the set. Then you make a new object inline, and ask the set if it has that object, and the answer is no because it's a different object.

However, if you ask the set of it contains `a` it returns true because you are using the same object that you used to put that object into the set in the first place.

I'm not sure how to advise you to fix this because I'm not sure how you really want to use this collection.

Comment: This set is working  , but when i trying to check that particular value is present or not in set , it's not working .


if(set.has({region,tableName})) { return true ;}
else { console.log("values doesn't exist in set ")} . 

I'm always getting else executed .

Comment: See my update that explains how object references in a set work.

Comment: How about `Map<Region, RegionBasedTable[]>`, then you could use has method as usual... only the setting is harder...